# Does Apache proxy_mod support repeated directives?

Tags: apache-2.4, puppet, mod-proxy

For example is:

```
<Proxy balancer://blah>
 BalancerMember ajp://127.0.0.1:8080
 Proxyset lbmethod=bytraffic
 Proxyset stickysession=JSESSIONID
 Proxyset timeout=5
</Proxy>
```

interpreted in the same way as:

```
<Proxy balancer://blah>
 BalancerMember ajp://127.0.0.1:8080
 Proxyset lbmethod=bytraffic stickysession=JSESSIONID timeout=5
</Proxy>
```

I ask because I am using the [Puppet Apache module](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache) to manage my configuration and it is currently producing my Proxyset directives on repeated lines (as per first example).

Answer (score 0):

Yes - it appears proxy_mod does support repeated directives on separate lines.

I enabled balancer manager support ("/balancer-manager") and I can see from that page that the values specified in each line are indeed set.